# Understanding GHC error "Qualified name in binding position"

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors, ghc

If I create a module `AModule` with a typeclass `Foo`,

```
module AModule where
class Foo a where
   bar :: a
```

and in another module `BModule` import `AModule` qualified and try to make some type an instance of `Foo`, i.e.

```
module B where
import qualified AModule as A
instance A.Foo Int where
   A.bar = 0
```

GHC tells me "Qualified name in binding position: A.bar".

From what I understand, this is related to [GHC ticket 3197](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/3197), which is labeled as fixed. I'm running GHC 6.12.1 and am still getting the error. Am I just misunderstanding something here?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You don't need the `A.` inside the instance declaration (See [Haskell 98 report §4.3.2](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html#sect4.3.2)).

The following compiles on 6.12.3:

```
instance A.Foo Int where    -- # A. here
   bar = 0                  -- # no A. here

main = print (A.bar :: Int) -- # A. here
```

Comment: Ah, of course. I misread a "not in scope" caused by a different line to think I needed the `A.`. Thanks a bunch!